# Compare user related objects in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm working on a Django project in which I have an article model, form, view.
The article has user field in its model and related_name as 'tagging'.
Now, i want to hide the article which is already created by user in Django templates,
How can I achieve this?

Something like:

```
{% if tag in articles  %}
```

**Update**
Here's my view as @andi requested:

```
class Tagging(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    cat = self.kwargs.get('cat')
    print(cat)
    queryset_list = Article.objects.all().filter(category=cat)

    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 1)
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {
        'articles': queryset,
        'page_request_var': page_request_var,
    }

    return render(request, 'users/tagging.html', context)
```

**My models**

> Both of these models are from different apps

TaggedArticle model:

```
choices = (
   ('yes', 'Yes'),
   ('no', 'No'),
   ('not sure', 'Not Sure'),
)

class TaggedArticle(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tagging')
  category_fit = models.CharField(choices=choices, max_length=255)
  article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='articles')
  relevant_feedback = models.TextField(blank=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
```

Article Model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField(max_length=255)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=Categories)
```

Help, me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to do it in the view by filtering the **QuerySet** which is passed further to the template.

Comment: both of these are separate objects how can i do that in views? please!

Comment: @AbdulRehman show your code in question and I will help. It depend you use class based views or function based views.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply exclude the ones by the user like this:

```
queryset_list = Article.objects.filter(category=cat).exclude(user=request.user)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Article & TaggedArticle are two different models, when an Article has been tagged by a user then it saves in a new model as TaggedArticle, now I need to hide Tagged articles in my template.As if I have query both of these (Article & TaggedArticle models) in view and pass as context for the template, but in template how can I hide the article if it's in TaggedArticle?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:** forgot a return statement!

You have several options:

- `Article.objects.filter(articles__is_null=True)` in alternative to @JahongirRamanov solution and if you don't need the whole queryset in the template
- If you want the whole queryset in the template and only "hide" within it: you need a different context, maybe somehting like:

  ```
   # models.py
   class Article(models.Model):
       ...
       def is_from_request_user(self, request):
            return TaggedArticle.objects.filter(article=self, user=request.user).exists()

   # views .py
       def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           ...
           context = {
                "articles" = [{"object": article, "from_user": article.is_from_request_user(request)} for article in queryset],
                ...,
            }

    # in template

    {% for article in articles %}
        {% if not article.from_user %}
        ...
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  ```

hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @efkin! thanks for your answer, but it's not working, I have displayed a message inside `{% if not ...%} Message here {% endif %}` it displays this message for all articles.

Comment: Just updated the answer, i forgot a return statement in the `is_from_request_user()` method -_-

Answer (score 0):

I have managed it by adding a link field also in TaggedArticle model then compare the link field from both Models in template and get the desired result.

Here's my updated TaggedArticle Model:

```
choices = (
  ('yes', 'Yes'),
  ('no', 'No'),
  ('not sure', 'Not Sure'),
)

class TaggedArticle(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tagging')
  category_fit = models.CharField(choices=choices, max_length=255)
  article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='articles')
  link = models.URLField(max_length=255,)
  relevant_feedback = models.TextField(blank=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
```

Here's my updated view:

```
class Tagging(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    cat = self.kwargs.get('cat')
    print(cat)
    queryset_list = Article.objects.all().filter(category=cat)
    tagged = TaggedArticle.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 1)
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {
        'articles': queryset,
        'page_request_var': page_request_var,
        'tagged': tagged,
    }

    return render(request, 'users/tagging.html', context)
```

Here's what i have done in template:

```
{% for art in articles %}
     {% for tag in tagged %}
          {% if tag.link in art.link %}
            <h2>Already Tagged</h2>
          {% endif%}
     {% endfor %} 
 {% endfor %}
```